# Hide layout if content is gone

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, visibility

I have a lot of different elements in a constraint layout.[image: with elements]
 It's not everytime the elements show, sometimes none.

When there is no elements visible, the layout looks like this [image: without elements]
I want to `setVisibility = Gone` if there are no elements in this layout.

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to check every child element if the visibility is gone?

(sorry that the images became extremely big)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this through data binding, something like this

```
android:visibility="@{viewmodel.panelVisibility}"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Can you please give me an example? i am not really sure what you mean. I am using databinding, but i know nothing about an panelvisibility

Comment: @Mayben So if you're using databinding correctly and each of those elements have a visibility change in your container view, then logically it should be easy to assign a visibility state to your container view based on the visibility variables in your viewmodel. The panelVisibility property I have here is just an example of the property being tracked/updated in your viewmodel.

For clarity, there is no Android component which automatically allows you to hide the container view if no inner elements visible, but using databinding this would be the cleanest approach.